# UITableView Splitting contents into Sections

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` for which I have listed the code below.

How do I section these objects out such as the following shown below?

***Math***
Algebra
Geometry
Calculus

***Science***
Integrated 1
Integrated 2

Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Math",@"Science",@"English",@"Social Studies",@"Spanish",@"German",@"French",@"Biology",nil];

    self.listData = array;
    [array release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use sectioned table view, that is the best way to achieve this. You can refer following tutorial for the same - http://www.xcode-tutorials.com/uitableview-–-3-sectioned-table-view/

Answer (score 0):

In your UITableViewDataSource of UITableView object;

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
   return array.count;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [array objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

will do the 'sectioning' part for your case.

Comment: IM HAVING AN ISSUE ITS NOT WORKING STILL...


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 return [self.listData count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
               SimpleTableIdentifier];

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
   return [yourarray count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [yourarray objectAtIndex:section];
}
```